# How to pass sql.Dataframe as an argument to a function in Scala

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to pass a Dataframe to a function in which I'm adding more columns into it
Currently the df has few columns in which i need to filter inside the function

When I try to pass the dataframe, it displays as Found sql.Dataframe - Required Dataframe.

```
val myData = sparksession.sql(" select query")

getFilteredDF(myData)

def getFilteredDF(myData:DataFrame): DataFrame={
     // adding few more columns and checks to df with .withcolumn()
}
```

Do I have to pass as Dataframe or Is there anyother type I need to give in order to pass it to the function?

Comment: did you import `org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame` at the beginning? anything else that you imported?

Comment: Yes I have used import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame. 

when i try to use the dataframe inside function I'm getting as Wrong forward reference

Answer (score 0):

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.lit
import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, SparkSession}
import spark.implicits._

def fAddCol(df: DataFrame): DataFrame = {
    df.withColumn("colOne", lit(1))
      .withColumn("colTwo", lit("test"))
}

val source = Seq(
    ("SUP_ID1", "Desc1"),
    ("SUP_ID2", "Desc2"),
    ("SUP_ID3", "Desc3"),
    ("SUP_ID4", "Desc4"),
    ("SUP_ID5", "Desc5"),
    ("SUP_ID6", "Desc6"),
    ("SUP_ID7", "Desc7")
).toDF("Key", "Desc")


val res = fAddCol(source)

res.printSchema()
//  root
//  |-- Key: string (nullable = true)
//  |-- Desc: string (nullable = true)
//  |-- colOne: integer (nullable = false)
//  |-- colTwo: string (nullable = false)

res.show(false)
//  +-------+-----+------+------+
//  |Key    |Desc |colOne|colTwo|
//  +-------+-----+------+------+
//  |SUP_ID1|Desc1|1     |test  |
//  |SUP_ID2|Desc2|1     |test  |
//  |SUP_ID3|Desc3|1     |test  |
//  |SUP_ID4|Desc4|1     |test  |
//  |SUP_ID5|Desc5|1     |test  |
//  |SUP_ID6|Desc6|1     |test  |
//  |SUP_ID7|Desc7|1     |test  |
//  +-------+-----+------+------+
```

Comment: Thanks you. But I'm facing issue with passing Dataframe to function. Not sure what am I missing. For eg: here df is not recogonizing inside my function and getting error as wrong forward reference. In my main function it is showing as sql.Dataframe as type.